# Replacing the default RequiredAttribute in a project with dynamically set required properties

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes

I have a MVC4 project which must provide a high level of flexibility. Specifically, the client must be able to configure which fields are required when filling up a form. These settings are read from an XML file on each successful login. I use the values from the config file in a custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` to the `ModelMetadata.IsRequired` property accordingly. This works well.

Now I need to add localization. I wrote a custom localized `RequiredAttribute` and registered it in the `Application_Start()` method. This also works as expected, but obviously I must explicitly decorate a property with it.

My problem is that I need to use my custom attribute instead of the standard `RequiredAttribute`. When I dynamically set a property as required, the system uses the default one, which does not suit my needs.

The question is, how do I force the framework to use my custom attribute instead of the default one, when validating a `Required` property?

Comment: You can try in your MetadataProvider in CreateMetadata method replace all RequiredAttribute with your custom RequiredAttribute and then call base implementation passing new array of attributes.

Comment: Certainly seams like a solution. I will test it and get back.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets, tried it. The attribute is correctly added to the attribute list. The problem I am facing now is that I can't seem to be able to configure the error message. All the changes I make are only reflected on the explicit attributes.

Comment: Did you try to provide ErrorMessage property for your custom requiredattribute when replacing standard? Maybe i do not fully understand what do you mean.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets, maybe I'm not fully woken up yet. My apologies. I abandoned (for now) the idea of using custom attributes. I just insert a new `RequiredAttribute` when appropriate (gets successfully added). After that I just set the `ErrorMessage` property to my custom error message. Although I can see the message being "saved" in the newly added attribute, I does not get rendered in my view. I get the old, standard error message. The new message gets however correctly displayed for all the attributes that have been explicitly set in my ViewModel.

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766186/asp-net-mvc-3-0-model-localization-with-regularexpression-attribute